# make widget (Button) transparent gtk

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I want to make my Buttons in my HMI transparent but I wasn't able to find any function, which could do that!

Using the code below I was only able make my background transparent but not the components.

```
Button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("MyButton");
gtk_window_set_opacity(GTK_Widget(Button), 0.3);
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem is most likely OS depended when reading the python docs for this function (I know you use C but that shouldn't be an issue), it mentions some remarks about the capabilities of the windowing system.

> **set_opacity**(opacity) [[source]](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkwidget.c?h=3.18.7#n15970)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - opacity (float) – desired opacity, between 0 and 1
>
> Request the `self` to be rendered partially
>   transparent, with opacity 0 being fully transparent and 1 fully
>   opaque. (Opacity values are clamped to the [0,1] range.). This works
>   on both toplevel widget, and child widgets, although there are some
>   limitations:
>
> For toplevel widgets this depends on the capabilities of the windowing
>   system. On X11 this has any effect only on X screens with a
>   compositing manager running. See `Gtk.Widget.is_composited()`. On
>   Windows it should work always, although setting a window’s opacity
>   after the window has been shown causes it to flicker once on Windows.
>
> For child widgets it doesn’t work if any affected widget has a native
>   window, or disables double buffering.

So assuming you still want to have a transparent button you could of course make a custom button based on a `Gtk.Image` in combination with an `EventBox` and the `button-press-event` and `button-release-event` signals. In which you could use any image and opacity you like.

As I'm more into Python person the example is in Python but it should be fairly easy to reproduce it in C:

```
class ImageButton(Gtk.EventBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gtk.EventBox, self).__init__()

        # Load the images for the button
        self.button_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("edit-delete", Gtk.IconSize.MENU)
        self.button_pressed_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("edit-delete-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.MENU)

        # Add the default image to the event box
        self.add(self.button_image)

        # Connect the signal listeners
        self.connect('realize', self.on_realize)
        self.connect('button-press-event', self.on_button_pressed)
        self.connect('button-release-event', self.on_button_released)


    def update_image(self, image_widget):
        self.remove(self.get_child())
        self.add(image_widget)
        self.button_pressed_image.show()

    def on_realize(self, widget):
        hand_pointer = Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.HAND1)
        window = self.get_window()
        window.set_cursor(hand_pointer)

    def on_button_pressed(self, widget, event):
        self.update_image(self.button_pressed_image)

    def on_button_released(self, widget, event):
        self.update_image(self.button_image)
```